# Remote search using Angular Material 2

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I have a list of about 4k items that I want the autocomplete input to search trough. Because it's really not that practical to fetch them in the constructor and filter them (as a few answers here suggest) in the angular app, I want to make the search on the server and return the data to the component.

I'm a bit lost on how the code should look like, but here's my attempt:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="w-100">
    <input #searchInput [matAutocomplete]="searchOptions" formControlName="search" matInput placeholder="Search"/>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-autocomplete #searchOptions="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items | async" [value]="item.id">
        {{ item.description }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

**Typescript**

```
export class SearchDialogComponent {

    myForm: FormGroup;
    items: any;

    constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        public itemService: ItemService,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SearchDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
            this.createForm();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.items = this.myForm.get('search').valueChanges.map(q => this.searchFilter(q));
    }

    createForm() {
        this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            search: new FormControl(''),
        });
    }

    searchFilter(q: string) {
        this.itemService.fullSearch(q).subscribe(result => {
            return result;   // This won't work, but I have no idea what will :) 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work then?

Comment: The `return` call is not in the scope of the `searchFilter` function, and the result isn't  returned to the `items` array. I hit the API, but the result is lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh! Then two things:

- Use `flatMap()` operator and perform the search service call;
- Do NOT subscribe to that observable, since you're using `async` pipe.

I assume that `itemService.fullSearch()` returns `Observable<T[]>` where `T` is result type.

**P.S.** This issue would take way less time if `any` was not in original code; and the signature of `searchFilter` method declared a return type. TypeScript is all about making JavaScript at least a bit type safer.

---

```
this.items = this.myForm
  .get('search')
  .valueChanges
  .flatMap(searchQuery => this.itemService.fullSearch(searchQuery));
```

Comment: Regarding the PS - I was trying anything and everything to make this work, so the declarations got lost in the process